# Neo4j Transaction in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher query, where I want to save user campaign with associate list. So I have two things to do, first save campaign and then add relationship with associate list. I have already completed this. But I want to improve my query like when user sent invalid list which are not in database, then there will be no campaign created. My query is given below:

```
MERGE (c:Campaigns { campaign_params: '${campaign_params_value}' } )

WITH c as c, c as c1
UNWIND {list} as att
MATCH(pl: List {id: att.listId })
WITH pl as pl, att as att, c as c, c as c1

MERGE (pl)-[buc:LIST_CAMPAIGN {templateId: att.templateId}]->(c1)

RETURN c
```

Here if `list` are empty or invalid data, still campaign will be created, but not `LIST_CAMPAIGN` relation will be created. So what I want is that, if any invalid or empty list is provided, then there will be no campaign created.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should be considered an invalid list?

Comment: invalid list mean `MATCH(pl: List {id: att.listId })` return empty

Comment: Inverting the MATCH & MERGE order is not enough? `UNWIND {list} as att
MATCH (pl: List {id: att.listId })

MERGE (c:Campaigns { campaign_params: '${campaign_params_value}' } )

MERGE (pl)-[buc:LIST_CAMPAIGN {templateId: att.templateId}]->(c1)

RETURN c`

Comment: @BrunoPeres, many many thanks, I'm working on it

Comment: Fot nothing... My solution worked for you?